# Attempting to create charts for multiple files with ggplot2. Only one is generating

Tags: sql-server, r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create some charts using data from a SQL table. The data from the sql table can be recreated with this example dataframe:

```
rw1 <- c("File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3", "File1", "File1", "File1", "File2", "File2", "File2", "File3", "File3", "File3")
rw2 <- c("0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.02", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03", "0.03")
rw3 <- c("Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final", "Time", "Size", "Final")
rw4 <- c(123, 456, 789, 312, 645, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498, 951, 753, 915, 438, 978, 741, 852, 963, 369, 258, 147, 753, 498)
rw5 <- c("01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12", "01/01/12")
rw6 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
rw7 <- c("Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Iteration", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release", "Release")
rw8 <- c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Cannot Connect to Database", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None")


df = data.frame(rw1, rw2, rw3, rw4, rw5, rw6, rw7, rw8)
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "Version", "Category", "Value", "Date", "Number", "Build", "Error")
```

---

Below is the code written for the SQL table. The code generates *a* chart perfectly. The problem is I need it to generate a chart for each File found under the `Name` column. Notice I've created a title using `files[i]`. I hope this is a key to understanding what I hope the outcome is. It would ideally have a chart for each file. I'm not sure why its only creating one.

```
library(ggplot2)

TestList <- list()

files<-unique(df$Name)

for (i in 1:3){
g<-ggplot(subset(df, Name == files[i] & !is.na(Value) & Deviation <.5) , aes(color = Value, x = Version, y = Deviation, group = Name)) + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(shape = Build), size = 4) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line") + 
  ggtitle(files[i]) + 
  ylab("Y-Axis Title") +
  scale_colour_gradient(name = 'Time (min)',low = 'blue', high = 'red') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1))

  TestList[[i]] <- g }

TestList
```

Comment: Regarding your example, do you think you could make it *simpler*? The goal is generally for a **minimal** reproducible example. Could you remove the code that there's no way we could run successfully (e.g., your db query and the following data transformations)? It's essentially clutter in your question. You've provided a nice reproducible data set, now delete the code that uses anything else. Trying to do a simple example with, say `mtcars` data might be even better.

Comment: As for your results, I'd like to know more about what *does* happen on your end. After running your code, what does `length(TestList)` give? Are you sure you're not producing all 3 plots and just not having time to see all of them?

Comment: I took out irrelevant code

Comment: The length of the list is correct for how many there should be. I think its throwing me that R studio is only showing one. Is there any way to get a scrolling list?

Comment: In RStudio, you can page through created plots using the left and right arrows at the top left corner of the plotting tab.

Comment: @Gregor How could I print all of the charts in a list? In say a .Rnw file

Comment: Inside a code chunk, `lapply(TestList, print)`.